# Creating multiple Choropleth map using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, select

I have created a choropleth map including a legend and a `div` element using a JavaScript object created from GeoJSON layer using the leaflet tutorial. But when I tried to create multiple choropleth maps from the same object it doesn't show on the map. I am beginner to Leaflet.

Here is the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
      .info {
        padding: 6px 8px;
        font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background: white;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      .info h4 {
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        color: #777;
      }
      .legend {
        line-height: 18px;
        color: #555;
      }
      .legend i {
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 8px;
        opacity: 0.7;
      }
      .cov_sel {
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border-color: brown;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/leaflet.zoomhome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/Control.MousePosition.css" />
    <link
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <script src="addis_ababa.js"></script>
    <script src="/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/leaflet.zoomhome.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/Control.MousePosition.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
    <script src="json/covid-19.js"></script>
    <title>My First Leaflet Map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map = L.map("map", { zoomControl: false }).setView(
        [8.9806, 38.7878],
        6
      );
      L.tileLayer("http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}", {
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains: ["mt0", "mt1", "mt2", "mt3"],
      }).addTo(map);

      function getColor(d) {
        return d > 100000 ? "#800026"
          : d > 50000 ? "#BD0026"
          : d > 15000 ? "#E31A1C"
          : d > 5000 ? "#FC4E2A"
          : "#FD8D3C";
      }
      function getColor2(d) {
        return d > 100000 ? "#8bd2da"
          : d > 50000 ? "#9edae0"
          : d > 15000 ? "#b1e1e7"
          : d > 5000 ? "#c5e9ed"
          : "#d8f0f3";
      }
      function style(feature) {
        return {
          fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Total_Case),
          weight: 2,
          opacity: 1,
          color: "white",
          dashArray: "3",
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
        };
      }
      function style2(feature) {
        return {
          fillColor: getColor2(feature.properties.Total_Deat),
          weight: 2,
          opacity: 1,
          color: "white",
          dashArray: "3",
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
        };
      }
      var cases = L.geoJson(covid_19, {
        filter: function (feature, layer) {
          return feature.properties.TotalCase;
        },
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
          layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature,
          });
          function highlightFeature(e) {
            var layer = e.target;

            layer.setStyle({
              weight: 5,
              color: "#666",
              dashArray: "",
              fillOpacity: 0.7,
            });

            if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
              layer.bringToFront();
            }
            info.update(layer.feature.properties);
          }

          function resetHighlight(e) {
            cases.resetStyle(e.target);
            info.update();
          }

          function zoomToFeature(e) {
            map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
          }

          var info = L.control();
          info.onAdd = function (map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info");
            this.update();
            return this._div;
          };

          info.onAdd = function (map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info");
            this.update();
            return this._div;
          };
          info.update = function (props) {
            this._div.innerHTML =
              "<h4>Number of Cases</h4>" +
              (props
                ? "<b>" + props.Region + " " + props.Total_Case + " People"
                : "Hover over a Region");
          };
          var legend = L.control({ position: "bottomright" });
          legend.onAdd = function (map) {
            var div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info legend"),
              grades = [5000, 15000, 50000, 100000],
              labels = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
              div.innerHTML +=
                '<i style="background:' +
                getColor(grades[i] + 1) +
                '"></i> ' +
                grades[i] +
                (grades[i + 1] ? "&ndash;" + grades[i + 1] + "<br>" : "+");
            }
            return div;
          };
          info.addTo(map);
          legend.addTo(map);
        },
      });

      var death = L.geoJson(covid_19, {
        filter: function (feature, layer) {
          return feature.properties.Total_Deat;
        },
        style: style2,
        onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
          layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature,
          });
          function highlightFeature(e) {
            var layer = e.target;

            layer.setStyle({
              weight: 5,
              color: "#666",
              dashArray: "",
              fillOpacity: 0.7,
            });

            if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
              layer.bringToFront();
            }
            info.update(layer.feature.properties);
          }

          //mouse out
          function resetHighlight(e) {
            death.resetStyle(e.target);
            info.update();
          }

          function zoomToFeature(e) {
            map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
          }

          var info2 = L.control();
          info2.onAdd = function (map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info");
            this.update();
            return this._div;
          };

          info2.onAdd = function (map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info");
            this.update();
            return this._div;
          };

          info2.update = function (props) {
            this._div.innerHTML =
              "<h4>Number of Deaths</h4>" +
              (props
                ? "<b>" + props.Region + " " + props.Total_Deat + " People"
                : "Hover over a Region");
          };
          var legend2 = L.control({ position: "bottomright" });
          legend.onAdd = function (map) {
            var div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info legend"),
              grades = [5000, 15000, 50000, 100000],
              labels = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
              div.innerHTML +=
                '<i style="background:' +
                getColor2(grades[i] + 1) +
                '"></i> ' +
                grades[i] +
                (grades[i + 1] ? "&ndash;" + grades[i + 1] + "<br>" : "+");
            }
            return div;
          };
          info2.addTo(map);
          legend2.addTo(map);
        },
      });

      cases.addTo(map);

      //scale
      L.control.scale().addTo(map);

      L.control.mousePosition().addTo(map);
      L.Control.zoomHome().addTo(map);
      var selection = L.control({ position: "topright" });
      selection.onAdd = function (map) {
        var div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info legend");
        div.innerHTML =
          '<select id="select"><option value="opt1">Covid-19 Cases - Season1</option>' +
          '<option value="opt2">Covid-19 Cases - Season2</option>' +
          '<option value="opt3">Covid-19 Cases - Season3</option>' +
          '<option value="opt4">Covid-19 Cases - Season4</option></select>';
        div.firstChild.onmousedown = div.firstChild.ondblclick =
          L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;
        return div;
      };
      selection.addTo(map);

      $("select").change(function (e) {
        var x = document.getElementById("select").value;
        if (x == "opt1") {
          map.removeLayer(death);
          map.addLayer(cases);
        } else if (x == "opt2") {
          map.removeLayer(cases);
          map.addLayer(death);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to switch between two different choroplet overlays? But you have menu with four selection items.

Comment: Any errors in your browser's console? The uppercase `C` in `L.Control.zoomHome()` is bothering me.

Comment: Thanks @IvanSanchez the capital C works and here is the error   Uncaught ReferenceError: legend is not defined
    at Object.onEachFeature (covid-19_2.php:225)
    at i.addData (GeoJSON.js:127)
    at i.addData (GeoJSON.js:107)
    at initialize (GeoJSON.js:92)
    at new i (Class.js:22)
    at Object.Ke (GeoJSON.js:439)
    at covid-19_2.php:168   and for the option let it work for two and will add the other two

Comment: Check your `legend2.onAdd`.

Comment: I have corrected the legends variable and added the jquery library the previous error was gone but still there is an error. Could not load content for http://localhost:8080/src/control/Control.Layers.js (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE).